# webview into sherlock fragment

Tags: android, webview

I have researched here in the forum but failing to implement a webview in sherlockfragment, what should I do?

```
public class LatestFragment extends SherlockFragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);
    return rootView;
}   
private WebView web_v;

public class OracoesActivity extends WebviewActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/oracoes.html", getResources().getString(R.string.menu_about));       
        //loadUrl("http://www.yoursite.com/about.html");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm using eclipse, and no error is not displayed, but when I open the emulator and squeegee the application does not appear and nothing in tab

Comment: There is really no need to use the ActionBarSherlock library now, and furthermore it's been deprecated by Jake Wharton: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock